# Inverter lista simplesmente encadeada

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

Fiz a implementação de uma lista encadeada e o método para listar os elementos, mas queria agora printar ela invertida (Por exemplo: 1>2>3 = 3>2>1). Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
//iniciamente a minha lista não aponta para lugar algum
public static Nodo inicio = null;

public static void print() {

    if (inicio == null) {
        System.out.println("Nada a exibir - a lista está vazia!");
    } else {
        Nodo aux = inicio;
        while (aux != null) {
            System.out.print(aux.getChave() + " ");
            aux = aux.getProx();
        }
    }
}

public void inserir(int e) {
    //criar um novo Nodo
    Nodo novo = new Nodo();
    novo.setChave(e);    //inserindo elemento
    novo.setProx(null); //depois dele não vem ninguém

    if (inicio == null) {
        inicio = novo; //aponto para o novo nodo
    } else {     //ja tem gente na lista ai precisa percorrer até chegar na null
        Nodo aux = inicio; //joga o aux no inicio
        while (aux.getProx() != null) {
            aux = aux.getProx();
        }
        aux.setProx(novo);
    }
}
```

A implementação da classe `Nodo` é a seguinte:

```
public class Nodo {

    public int chave;
    public Nodo prox;
    public Nodo ant;

    //+ métodos acessores
}
```

Comment: Coloca um print depois do metodo recursivo, assim ele vai printar de trás pra frente. Se colocar o print antes do metodo recursivo, ele vai printar na ordem.

Comment: Faltam informações, não sei como o Nodo foi implementado.

Comment: Pronto, atualizei!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa é primeiro inverter a lista, usando [este algoritmo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/):

```
public void inverter() {
    Nodo prev = null;
    Nodo next = null;
    Nodo current = inicio;
    while (current != null) {
        next = current.getProx();
        current.setProx(prev);
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    inicio = prev;
}
```

Basicamente, você parte do início e vai iterando na lista, e a cada nó você faz o elemento N ser o próximo do elemento N + 1. Por fim, o início da lista passa a ser o último nó encontrado. Repare que se a lista for vazia (ou seja, se `inicio` for `null`), ele nem entra no `while`, e ao final, o início continua sendo `null` (a lista continuará - corretamente - vazia).

Para entender melhor como esse algoritmo funciona:

[image: inverter lista ligada]

Depois de inverter a lista, basta imprimí-la normalmente, usando o método `print()`.

---

#### Sem precisar inverter a lista

Outra alternativa, mas sem precisar inverter a lista, é imprimí-la recursivamente:

```
public void printInvertido(Nodo nodo) {
    if (nodo != null) {
        printInvertido(nodo.getProx());
        System.out.print(nodo.getChave() + " ");
    }
}
```

Neste caso, não precisa inverter a lista, basta chamar `printInvertido(inicio)`. As chamadas recursivas vão sendo feitas para todos os elementos da lista, e como a impressão só ocorre depois destas, os elementos são impressos na ordem inversa.

**Obs**: o método acima não trata o caso da lista vazia, então bastaria criar mais um método para tratar este caso:

```
public void printInvertido() {
    if (inicio == null) {
        System.out.println("Nada a exibir - a lista está vazia!");
    } else {
        printInvertido(inicio);
    }
}
```

Assim, basta chamar `printInvertido()` diretamente. Se a lista for vazia, imprime a mensagem específica. Caso não seja vazia, chama o método recursivo, que imprime a lista invertida.

Lembrando que, caso a lista seja muito grande, essa quantidade toda de chamadas recursivas [pode causar um `StackOverflowError`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18368406).

---

#### Outra alternativa: transformar a lista em duplamente encadeada

Que tal aproveitar que a sua classe `Nodo` também possui uma referência para o elemento anterior? Ou seja, vamos torná-la duplamente encadeada - estou assumindo que o campo `ant` não foi criado à toa.

No seu código atual você não usa a referência para o anterior, então bastariam alguns ajustes para usar esta informação. Por exemplo, poderia ser criada uma classe `Lista` assim:

```
public class Lista {

    private Nodo inicio = null;
    private Nodo fim = null;

    public void inserir(int e) {
        Nodo novo = new Nodo(e);
        if (inicio == null) {
            inicio = fim = novo; // aponto para o novo nodo
        } else { // insere no final
            fim.setProx(novo);
            novo.setAnt(fim);
            fim = novo;
        }
    }

    public void print(boolean invertido) {
        if (inicio == null) {
            System.out.println("Nada a exibir - a lista está vazia!");
        } else {
            // se for invertido, começa do final, senão, começa do início
            Nodo aux = invertido ? fim : inicio;
            while (aux != null) {
                System.out.print(aux.getChave() + " ");
                // se for invertido, vai para o anterior, senão, vai para o próximo
                aux = invertido ? aux.getAnt() : aux.getProx();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E na classe `Nodo`, acrescentei este construtor:

```
public Nodo(int chave) {
    this.chave = chave;
    this.prox = null;
    this.ant = null;
}
```

Pois me parece que não faz sentido criar um `Nodo` cuja chave não tenha algum valor, então não teria necessidade de existir o construtor sem argumentos (pois no seu código você cria um `Nodo` e depois seta o valor da chave, mas se este é obrigatório, por que não manter apenas um construtor que obriga a passar este valor?). [Só crie construtores que façam sentido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052).

Agora eu tenho o início e o fim da lista, e o método `inserir` sempre insere no final, ou seja, logo depois de `fim`. Veja que eu acerto as referências para o próximo e o anterior, assim a lista será duplamente ligada.

Já no método `print()` eu passo um parâmetro indicando se deve imprimir invertido ou não. Dependendo do valor deste *booleano*, eu começo do início ou do fim da lista, e no `while` eu avanço para o anterior ou para o próximo (no caso, `invertido ? fim : inicio` significa que, se `invertido` for `true`, eu uso o `fim`, e se for `false`, eu uso o `inicio` - a mesma lógica vale para determinar se eu pego o próximo ou o anterior).

Sendo assim, se eu chamar `print(false)`, ele imprime a lista na ordem normal, e `print(true)` imprime na ordem inversa. Ex:

```
Lista list = new Lista();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.inserir(i);
}
System.out.println("Ordem normal: ");
list.print(false);

System.out.println("\nInvertida: ");
list.print(true);
```

Saída:

```
Ordem normal: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Invertida: 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: Adorei o gif da inversão!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Esse gif é muito bom, né? Teria sido muito mais legal se minhas aulas de estruturas de dados tivessem sido com gifs...

Comment: Sanou todas as minhas duvidas, perfeito!